# thread not running in background

Tags: android, multithreading

i am calling this function from the menu and calls the upload(item) function to pass the index of the selected priority.

```
public void showPriorityDialog()
{
    final CharSequence[] priority = {"1 Hour", "12 Hours", "24 Hours", "Cancel"};

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setTitle("Select Priority");
    builder.setItems(priority, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int item) {
            if(item != 3)
                upload(item);
        }
    });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();
}
```

however, whenever i call the upload function, the thread doesn't run in background, and the OS thinks that the app is not responding due to executing timeout.

```
public void upload(int priority)
{    
        final int _priority = priority;
        uploadThread = new Thread()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                try
                {
                    super.run();                    

                    mHandler.post(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            try
                            {
                                //ftp commands...
                            }
                            catch (Exception e)
                            {
                                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }


                        }
                    });

                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), e.toString() , Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }                   
        };
        uploadThread.start();

}
```

am i doing something wrong? TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `mHandler.post()`, your entire Runnable executes on UI thread and your background thread just exits. To fix, do FTP before posting to handler. Then do `mHandler.post()` to have Toast appear. Note that you `catch` also need to display Toast via post.